# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'scrollLeft' in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

According to the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and some examples found here, scrollLeft is a valid argument for `animate()`. However, I keep getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'scrollLeft' in undefined`.

```
$('#prev a, #next a').click(function() {
    $(window).animate({scrollLeft: 500}, 1000);
});
```

Is there something simple and silly that I am overlooking? What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The window doesn't have a scrollbar, it belongs to the body or the documentElement (html tag) :

```
$('#prev a, #next a').click(function() {
    $('body, html').animate({scrollLeft: 500}, 1000);
});
```

Strange as it may seem you can get the windows scrollLeft property with `css()`, but when animating, you animate the body and html tags.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, it must have been something simple and silly I am overlooking. Merci.